# Club childschema Under parent on mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose module
I have two Schema file

```
//First User File
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserActivitySchema = require('./useractivity')
//User Schema
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    activity: [UserActivitySchema]
});
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'User');
```

> I already Tried to Create a subdocument but not able to acheive it

```
//Second Schema i.e supposed to be child is on useractivity.js file
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//User Activity Schema....011217
var UserActivitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
        message_count:{
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
});
exports.UserActivitySchema = UserActivitySchema;
```

By this, It will  create the Entry like this:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ab38941ffbb87124c673862"),
 "username" : "peter",
 "activity" : []

}
```

What I want is to like this:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ab38941ffbb87124c673862"),
 "username" : "peter",
 "activity" : {
   "message_count" : 0   
 } 
}
```

Any help is really Appreciated..

Comment: Do you want to store a reference of `UserActivitySchema` in `activity`? For example, save an `UserActivity` and get it along with the user?

Comment: yes i want the same

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose `populate` can help you to get the required functionalities. You can learn more about `populate` [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). You can do it in this way,

**Create `UserActivitySchema`**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var UserActivitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
        message_count:{
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserActivity', UserActivitySchema, 'UserActivity');
```

**Now create `UserSchema` like this**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserActivitySchema = require('./useractivity')
//User Schema
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    activity: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'UserActivity',
    }
});
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'User');
```

Now, while you are saving a user save the `_id` of the `UserActivity` in `activity`

When you are making your query to get user you can do like this

```
User.findOne({_id: 5ab38941ffbb87124c673862})
.populate('UserActivity')
.exec(function(err, user) {
    // do stuff with returned user
});
```